What can I do to stop the Keyboard destroying my layout in SwiftUI view?
I got some problem, what I hardly can solve by myself and I hope for your help :)
I have programmed an app. Unfortunately, the layout is destroyed when I call up the keyboard. What can I do? I tested everthing from constrains, until safe area and some libaries but nothings works  so far
Thank you all in advance for  your help :)




import SwiftUI

struct RegisterUserView: View {
    @State private var username = ""
    @State private var email = ""
    @State private var password = ""
    @State private var confirmPassword = ""
    @State private var isTermsAccepted = false

    let backgroundImage = "backgroundlogin"

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Image(backgroundImage)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .ignoresSafeArea()

                ScrollView {
                    VStack(spacing: 20) {
                        Text("Neuer Account")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .font(.custom("Avenir", size: 40))
                            .fontWeight(.bold)

                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 15) {
                            TextField("Dein Name", text: $username)
                                .padding()
                                .background(Color.white.opacity(0.7))
                                .cornerRadius(10)
                                .font(.custom("Avenir", size: 18))
                                .padding(.horizontal, 40)

                            TextField("E-Mail", text: $email)
                                .padding()
                                .background(Color.white.opacity(0.7))
                                .cornerRadius(10)
                                .font(.custom("Avenir", size: 18))
                                .padding(.horizontal, 40)

                            SecureField("Passwort", text: $password)
                                .padding()
                                .background(Color.white.opacity(0.7))
                                .cornerRadius(10)
                                .font(.custom("Avenir", size: 18))
                                .padding(.horizontal, 40)

                            SecureField("Passwort bestätigen", text: $confirmPassword)
                                .padding()
                                .background(Color.white.opacity(0.7))
                                .cornerRadius(10)
                                .font(.custom("Avenir", size: 18))
                                .padding(.horizontal, 40)

                            HStack {
                                CheckboxView(isChecked: $isTermsAccepted)
                                Text("Ich akzeptiere die AGBs und die Datenschutzbedingungen")
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    .font(.custom("Avenir", size: 18))
                            }
                            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                            .padding(.vertical, 20)
                        }
                        .padding(.horizontal)

                        Button("Registrieren") {
                            // Registrierungslogik hier einfügen
                        }
                        .padding()
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .disabled(!isTermsAccepted)
                    }
                    .padding()
                }
                .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true) // Behält das Ausblenden des standardmäßigen "Zurück"-Buttons bei
    }
}

struct CheckboxView: View {
    @Binding var isChecked: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: isChecked ? "checkmark.square.fill" : "square")
            .foregroundColor(isChecked ? .blue : .gray)
            .onTapGesture {
                self.isChecked.toggle()
            }
    }
}

struct RegisterUserView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        RegisterUserView()
    }
}




What are you expecting the result to be? The keyboard has to take some space on screen, so what is your ideal layout when it is visible?

I found the solution. You should move your image from ZStack to .background of your ScrollView. And add .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true) to you NavigationView.

var body: some View {
                NavigationView {
                    ScrollView {
                        VStack(spacing: 20) {
                            Text("Neuer Account")
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                .font(.custom("Avenir", size: 40))
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
        
                            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 15) {
                                TextField("Dein Name", text: $username)
                                    .padding()
                                    .background(Color.white.opacity(0.7))
                                    .cornerRadius(10)
                                    .font(.custom("Avenir", size: 18))
                                    .padding(.horizontal, 40)
        
                                TextField("E-Mail", text: $email)
                                    .padding()
                                    .background(Color.white.opacity(0.7))
                                    .cornerRadius(10)
                                    .font(.custom("Avenir", size: 18))
                                    .padding(.horizontal, 40)
        
                                SecureField("Passwort", text: $password)
                                    .padding()
                                    .background(Color.white.opacity(0.7))
                                    .cornerRadius(10)
                                    .font(.custom("Avenir", size: 18))
                                    .padding(.horizontal, 40)
        
                                SecureField("Passwort bestätigen", text: $confirmPassword)
                                    .padding()
                                    .background(Color.white.opacity(0.7))
                                    .cornerRadius(10)
                                    .font(.custom("Avenir", size: 18))
                                    .padding(.horizontal, 40)
        
                                HStack {
                                    CheckboxView(isChecked: $isTermsAccepted)
                                    Text("Ich akzeptiere die AGBs und die Datenschutzbedingungen")
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                        .font(.custom("Avenir", size: 18))
                                }
                                .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                                .padding(.vertical, 20)
                            }
                            .padding(.horizontal)
        
                            Button("Registrieren") {
                                // Registrierungslogik hier einfügen
                            }
                            .padding()
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .background(Color.blue)
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                            .disabled(!isTermsAccepted)
                        }
                        .padding()
                    }
                    .background {
                        Image(backgroundImage)
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                            .ignoresSafeArea()
                    }
                    .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
                }
                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            }

